# Errors when utilizing acronyms

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

When trying to create a nomenclature utilizing acronyms two errors mainly occur:

I try to utilize `$\dot{\bullet}$` in order to indicate a first order time derivative and I get a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error.

Also, when trying to represent matrices with squared brackets as, for example: `\acro{[A]}{state matrix}` it comes out as ][A ]]state matrix.

What should be done in these cases?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: `\dots` (with s) is not an accent, it makes `. . .`  you want `\dot`  .